# Whats wrong with my SQL query?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to set up a query that shows the first post of each thread and is ordered by the date of the last post in each thread. I got the first part down with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT Min( ID ) AS MinID
FROM test_posts
GROUP BY Thread
)tmin

JOIN test_posts ON test_posts.ID = tmin.MinID
```

Now I need to figure out how to call the last post of each thread into a table, than use that table to order the first tables results. So far I got this, but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT Min( ID ) AS MinID
FROM test_posts
GROUP BY Thread
)tmin

JOIN test_posts ON test_posts.ID = tmin.MinID 

ORDER BY (SELECT MAX( ID ) AS MaxID, Thread, MAX( Date )
FROM test_posts
GROUP BY Thread
)tmax

tmax.Date
```

Comment: Not checked your syntax in detail, but what's that tmax.Date at the end there? Are you trying to group by that too? If so, there needs to be a comma between tmax and tmax.Date.
Also, it would be a good idea to tell us your error, rather than just saying "It doesn't work".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select minid
  from (select min(id) as min_id, 
               max(id) as max_id, 
               max(date) as max_date
               thread
          from test_posts
         group by thread ) t_min_max
       inner join test_posts on test_posts.id = t_min_max.min_id
 order by max_id, thread, max_date
```

You can't order by a subquery, but you can order by columns/expressions from a preceding subquery.  I'm not exactly sure how you intend to sort it, but you've got all the expressions there.